# How to protect certain ranges?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to protect certain ranges and allow users to continue to use the grouping functionality once the selected area is protected.

The code asks me to establish a password, then gives me

> Run-time error 438' Object doesn't support this property or method.

```
Sub allowGroup()
    Set mySheet = Application.Range("A1:S23,P26:S53,B38:O38,B53:O53")
    Dim myPW As String
    myPW = Application.InputBox("Type one Password to protect your worksheet:", "allowGroup", "", Type:=2)
    mySheet.Protect Password:=myPW, Userinterfaceonly:=True
    mySheet.EnableOutlining = True
End Sub
```

The line highlighted in debug is `mySheet.Protect Password:=myPW, Userinterfaceonly:=True`.

Comment: Does that mean I should be using mySheet.Locked ratherthan mySheet.Protect?  I tried that, and now get Run-time error '1004'" Application-defined or object-defined error.  Apologies, this type of code is very new for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worksheets are protected, ranges are locked. You have named a range object in a confusing manner so it looks like it would be a worksheet object. EnableOutlining is also a worksheet property, that will error as well.

You need to unlock all the cells you want to modify and lock those you want to be immutable.

This should do what you are looking for:

```
Sub allowGroup()
    Dim lockrange As Range
    Set lockrange = Range("A1:S23,P26:S53,B38:O38,B53:O53")
    
    ActiveSheet.EnableOutlining = True
    Range(Cells.Address).Locked = False
    lockrange.Locked = True
    
    Dim myPW As String
    myPW = Application.InputBox("Type one Password to protect your worksheet:", "allowGroup", "", Type:=2)
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=myPW, Userinterfaceonly:=True
    
End Sub
```